# HttpLoggingInterceptor (OkHttp3) logging a lot of times for each request

Tags: android, logging, interceptor, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to do some requests using Retrofit2 and OkHttp3, and intercepting them using HttpLoggingInterceptor. I am injecting the OkHttp client using Dagger.. and it's all ok but when I just make a request to my server I can see the request and response logged in Logcat three or more times when it should be just one time..

The part of the code where I am setting the interceptor is like:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY); 
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
```

Example Logcat result, for just ONE request called:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://date.jsontest.com/ http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://date.jsontest.com/ http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://date.jsontest.com/ http/1.1
```

Which can be the problem? Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here (the answer of shahsurajk which commented on 24 Sep 2017):
[https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/12427](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1242)

> I had an HTTPLogger and chain.proceed(..) in one interceptor itself. So assuming that HTTPLogger internally also calls chain.proceed() which thus makes two requests, I added a networkinterceptor and moved the HTTPLogger to the network interceptor and my custom apikey chain.proceed(...) In other interceptor. Which worked as a charm and the API was called only once internally. Thus you need to look for code which can possibly call the chain.proceed(..) method internally. Which makes a new request.

For me worked the changing of:

```
httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
```

to:

```
httpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(logging);
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding @Singleton annotation to Dagger. Maybe, you add several loggers instead of one

Comment: It's already as a @Singleton and it stills over-logging... :(

Comment: In our project we have added interceptor two times by calling addInterceptor method two times. Thank you.